# Sencha Touch 2 native build vs wrapping Sencha Touch 2 in Phonegap

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I know there are a few questions pitting Sencha Touch 2 against Phonegap, and that is not what I mean to do here. I have been planning to build my Webapp using Sencha Touch 2 and wrapping it in Phonegap; but I just found out that Sencha Touch 2 also all allows you to build a native version of your web-app for Android and ios using there command line tool.  Why haven't I heard much about this solution? What are the limitations with doing this? And what is better, using Sencha Touch 2's native build feature or going the Sencha Touch 2 + Phonegap route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that Sencha Touch 2 native packaging will still be using UIWebViews (like PhoneGap) so the performance will be similar. Personally I would stick with PhoneGap/Cordova as it's a more mature product with a larger user base. You can still use the Sencha Touch 2 framework but still bundle/publish the app with xcode.

Comment: Thank for the insight. When you say "bundle/publish the app with xcode", are you saying not to go with Sencha + phonegap?

Comment: When you create a native app with PhoneGap for iOS, you have to use Apple's xcode to compile the app and send it to the app store for review. That being said, you can also use PhoneGap Build to create all of your apps for you (iOS/Android/etc) without using xcode/eclipse/etc.