# Maximal reuse: Webservice, Android client, Web Client, how?

Tags: android, gwt, service, wsdl, restlet

I need to build a simple web service in Java, the context is Google Application Engine.
Two clients are needed as well: Android and Web Page, for browser.

I consider something like Restlet, and want to re-use from it Android and GWT clients.

Could, you, please, give me a hint, whether it is a good way to go?
Could you advice others?

In particular, I could not find, how this technology coexists with WSDL, and if
I am going to be able to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Restlet Framework is mainly used to develop RESTful web services, even though in practice you can also issue and receive SOAP calls to bridge with older systems (no WSDL support though).

For help on GWT and Android client sides, see:

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on whether you wish to build cross platform as in phonegap or keep it simple as in mobilewebapp example provided in sample folder in gwt zip file you download.

The mobilewebapp sample does not access smartphone features but will be accessible by browser on any mobile. phonegap or similar frameworks like titanium,sencha provide api to access smartphone features.

Fore more information -

http://www.sapandiwakar.in/technical/api-research-study-iphone-and-android-applications/

[Sencha Touch 2 native build vs wrapping Sencha Touch 2 in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642897/sencha-touch-2-native-build-vs-wrapping-sencha-touch-2-in-phonegap)

[Creating a mobile app using Google App Engine and GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575744/creating-a-mobile-app-using-google-app-engine-and-gwt/13576518#13576518)